# SP2010 Foundation Error Event ID 6875

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, error

I've been trying to figure out this error that keeps coming up on my SP2010 Foundation server event viewer:

> Error loading and running event receiver TaskAlert.Assigner in TaskAlert, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=8c9fc716f38d08b2 . Additional information is below.
>   : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I currently have 3 sites but 1 site is causing this anytime an item is created on a list.

I've tried repairing the SP install, patching to the latest CU, and cleared my config cache but it is still doing it and it has SP2. This has to be something site related since the other 2 sites with the same workflow does not cause this error but I am lost.

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler you mention is not a part of Standard SharePoint. All assemblies in SP 2010 have version 14. Moreover there's no TaskAlert assembly in standard SP. You may use following SQL command in your SP content database to try find the list where is registered:

```
select * from AllLists where tp_ID in(SELECT distinct HostId FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[EventReceivers] where class like 'TaskAlert')
```

But if the exception is thrown when item is created in any list on the site then the event receiver may be registered on content type or site collection.

You may either deregister the event receiver (you may use tool like [SharePoint event receiver manager](https://speventreceiverman.codeplex.com/)) or repair it.

Comment: I just spent some time deleting /adding each column on my list to see if it is one of the columns.  I found out that if I re-add the site column "Assigned To" column the error stopped. Would you happen to know why if this column is missing it would give these errors? I also have send task to email notification OFF but it will still send an email when I re-add the Assigned to column and specify a user. I'm guessing it is giving that error because its trying to send an email task?

Comment: I downloaded the sharepoint event receiver and deleted taskalert.assigner under the "ItemAdded" event receiver in the list and it fixed the issue. Thank you for your help